# Is there a way to type a recursive dataclass?

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-dataclasses

Suppose you have the following dataclass

```
@dataclass
class Task:
    subTasks: Optional[List[Task]]
```

This is not possible, since `Task` is not declared yet.

I am using Python 3.6 w/ `dacite` + `dataclasses` to parse a large dictionary into a dataclass.

Currently I've been doing it like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from dacite import from_dict

@dataclass
class Task:
    subTasks: Optional[List]

    def process_sub_tasks(self) -> None:
        cls = type(self)
        if self.subTasks:
            self.subTasks = [from_dict(data_class=cls, data=d) for d in self.subTasks]
            for subtask in self.subTasks:
                subtask.process_sub_tasks()
```

I was wondering if there's a way to type `subTasks` somehow to make it know that it is also a `List[Task]` object, rather than a generic `List`

Comment: Incidentally, it's a lot cleaner to have `subTasks` be an empty list instead of `None` for a task with no subtasks.

Comment: Maybe. However, I am writing this to mostly be identical to the product I'm testing, so that the typing listed on the API Documentation for the product is identical to what's written here. It helps in maintaining future changes, since the product is still changing a lot.. I do agree with  you though, that subTasks should ideally always be a List.

Comment: I also noticed with the duplicated question, that it would require that I pass forward references to every call to `from_dict` in `dacite` using `Config(forward_references={"Y": Y})` (which is inconvenient :/) otherwise subTasks elements won't have that type, which I assume would only be solved via 3.7's annotation.

Comment: If anyone else is reading, this doesn't work with `pydantic` in python 3.6 because of [Issue 463](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/463)